# Second-order Neumann boundary condition discretization

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Let the following problem
$$\text{div}\left(\frac{\nabla u}{v}\right)=f\quad\text{on }]0,1[\times]0,1[,$$
where the given functions $v(x,y)$ and $f(x,y)$ are defined on $[0,1]$ and they are sufficiently smooth.

How can I discretize, by a second-order finite difference method, the boundary condition $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$ on the left boundary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ghost points at $(-h_x,y)$, then take $\frac{u(h_x,y)-u(-h_x,y)}{2h_x}=0$ so that $u(-h_x,y)=u(h_x,y)$. Then use the actual PDE at $(0,y)$ (which is where this value $u(-h_x,y)$ enters into the solution).

This assumes a uniform grid, but it is fairly straightforward to extend to a non-uniform grid.

Comment: You want to say $\frac{u(h_x,y)-u(-h_x,y)}{2h_x}$

Comment: @Houssam Yes, thanks.

Comment: But $u(0,y)$ is not given also

Comment: @Houssam It doesn't have to be; ultimately you're trying to set up a system of linear equations for the values of $u$ at the grid points. The only *a priori* problem with defining the discretization of the PDE at $(0,y)$ is that $(-h_x,y)$ doesn't exist (for $y \neq 0,y \neq 1$, at least). Introducing the ghost point and then giving it an equation to relate it to the other $u$ values fixes that problem.

Comment: Thanks Ian. But I think that the problem is more complicated: for example, if we consider the 1D problem $$\begin{cases}u''(x)=f(x)&\text{on }]0,1[\\u'(0)=0\text{ and }u(1)=0\end{cases}$$
then by discretizing $u'(0)=0$ by $u_{-1}=u_1$ and the equation on the interior points by $\dfrac{u_{i+1}-2u_i+u_{i-1}}{h^2}$, for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$, we obtain $n$ equations with $n+1$ unknowns $u_{-1},u_0,\ldots,u_{n-1}$. Moreover, the first equation $ \dfrac{u_{2}-2u_1+u_0}{h^2}$ does not contain $u_{-1}$

Comment: @Houssam As I said, in this framework you also define the PDE on what looks like the "boundary", so that in the 1D problem there is an equation $\frac{u_1-2u_0+u_{-1}}{h^2}=\frac{2u_1-2u_0}{h^2}=f(0)$. So the PDE gives $n$ equations, the BCs give $2$ equations, and there are $n+2$ unknowns (assuming the right side is Dirichlet).

Comment: The equations $\frac{u_{i+1}-2u_i+u_{i-1}}{h^2}$ are defined on the interior points only: $u''(x)=f(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$ nor at $x=1$.
The PDE gives $n-1$ equations.

Comment: @Houssam I can tell you that this works. Your objection amounts to an issue of interpretation, which should really be answered through a derivation. One way of looking at it is to view the non-ghost points as really being in the *interior* of the domain so that your numerical solution does not really see a small region close to the Neumann boundary.

Comment: Another (better) way is to use the weak formulation and get the finite difference formulation by setting up the resulting integral equation with a specific set of test functions and then approximate this integral by quadrature. A still better way is to just use finite elements to begin with.

Comment: Thanks Ian, it works.